# How to add 2 field in logstash.conf file

Tags: logstash, filebeat, grok

I have 2 fields in my filebeat

```
  fields:
    info: test1
    name: test3
```

How i can concat so it become test1-test3 in my logstash configuration file

```
  mutate {
    add_field => { "name" => "%{[fields][name]}" }
  }
```

the reason for it so that i can do

```
if [name] in ["test1-test3","test1-test2"]
.....
```

or is there a better way to perform it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use both values in the `add_field` with the `-` as a separator.

```
 mutate {
    add_field => { "name" => "%{[fields][info]}-%{[fields][name]}" }
  }
```

Comment: Can I know is there a better way to do it. I want use in if statement. As this will introduce new field and later i need remove it. is there better approach